# LOCALTIMESTAMP precision issue in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, timestamp, oracle-apex-5.1

The table I am working on has a date_time column, which take timestamp as a data type. When I created a data entry form for it using APEX, I set the default value of that column using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. However, all entries I created with that form ended up having the same value for that column, which is midnight (24-APR-23 12.00.00.000000 AM). When I tried to create entries using SQL commands instead, I received the correct time. Since my work will involve time comparison in the future, could you help me make it so that CURRENT_TIMESTAMP would return the correct time on a form? Thank you

Comment: It sounds like the form is capturing or sending a plain date with time set to midnight. It would be helpful to edit your question to show what you are actually doing in Apex.

Comment: @AlexPoole I just edit my question. Please feel free to ask if you are not clear on anything

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, I created a table

```
create table a1_test (id number, ts timestamp);
```

and - in Apex - interactive report with a form. I modified only TS column's

- "default value" property to "expression" and put `localtimestamp` in there
- "format mask" to `dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss,ff9`. Why? Because - when I ran IR and clicked on Create button - Apex automatically displayed default value in that format

Then, if you want, modify IR column's format to anything you want.

Result (form above, report below):

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response. How can I find the format mask that you spoke of? I am new to this

Comment: Just run the page for the first time as is; Apex will display timestamp value in default format.